# breeze: validating navigation property on change

Tags: breeze

I have a navigation property, which I added a custom validator to.

The validator triggers fine when saving the entity. However it does not trigger when adding/removing entities from the navigation property.

Should I subscribe to propertyChanged event, or is there another way to handle this ?

Also, why is there not a propertyChanged event per property instead of having to subscribe to any properties change ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two kinds of navigation properties, scalar and nonscalar. A scalar property is something like 'Order.Customer' where an order has a single customer associated with it.  Setting or changing the customer in this case will fire the entityAspect.propertyChanged event.

For a nonscalar property like say 'Customer.Orders', accessing the property returns an array of orders associated with the customer.

This is always the same array.  Orders can be added or removed from it, but the returned array itself is always the same. Because the array itself is never changed a property change is NOT fired for these operations.

However you CAN watch the array itself for changes, see the [arrayChanged event](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/default/files/apidocs/classes/%E2%86%88_relationArray_.html#events)
in the breeze Api docs.

As for why there is no separate event that you can register to fire only when a specific property is changed, the reason is that the current mechanism supports your ability to do this while at the same time allowing for those use cases where you want to see 'all' of the changes to an entity without having to register what could potentially be tens of thousand of events.

Remember entity property level events, if they existed, would have to be registered on as many entities as are in your cache (100's or 1000's) times the number of properties on your entities (5-50).

Most of what is described here is fairly standard for entity change tracking in a number of environments across a variety of programming languages.  We didn't try to reinvent the idea, but simply reimplemented a pretty common standard.